# Minify _WITHOUT_ combine using requireJS

Tags: requirejs

My program is using `RequireJS` to manage dependencies in javascript, and it works fine - except that I have an issue where the only way to do the minification is to use the `r.js` optimization system to do minify and combine when I compile the application.

This does work; I have it functioning how I need it to - but it is very wasteful because it puts all of the scripts in a single document. This seems to defeat the entire purpose of the module loading - and it makes the site a great deal slower.

Is there a way - other than manually minifying each file, every time I change them, to have this optimizer keep files separated so that the module loading can still only pull the files it needs?

I am doing the minification/combination using `nodejs` with a build event in `Visual Studio`, similar to this;

## build.bat

```
node minify.js -o build.json
```

## build.json

```
{
    "baseUrl" : "../../home", 
    "name": "../lib/app/config", 
    "include": [
          // each file gets listed here
    ], 
    "exclude": [], 
    "optimize": "none", 
    "out": "program.js", 
    "insertRequire": [
        "../lib/app/config"
      ]
}
```

## config.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/app_content/scripts',
});
```

## Visual Studio Build Event

```
node "$(ProjectDir)scripts\lib\app\minify.js" -o "$(ProjectDir)scripts\lib\app\build.json"
```

So this makes a huge `program.js` file that has everything - with explicitly named modules. It runs and functions, but ... again, that kind of defeats the purpose, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it makes the site a great deal slower

That can't be true, concatenating into a single file reduces the amount of necessary HTTP requests for a page and should improve performance quite a bit. If you just want to minify your files, use a tool that does just that - e.g. [UglifyJS](https://github.com/hughsk/uglifyify).

Comment: It makes the site slower because it loads the entire javascript system, which is considerably large in filesize. I thought one of the goals of requirejs is to only load the needed files on demand.

Comment: There is no on-demand loading in RequireJS (unless you wrap your `require()` calls in if clauses) and that's not one of its goals. Network connections are very slow compared to the JavaScript interpreter itself, it's almost always faster to serve a few bytes more up front than to do an additional HTTP request when something is missing.

Comment: Hey, I had honestly forgotten about this question. A lot has happened since I asked it and yes, you are correct, the site slowdown was not the fault of requirejs.